# How do I display icon on FloatingActionButton?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have a problem displaying the icon on FloatingActionButton. The icon loses transparency. I have compileSdkVersion 28.

The dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

}
```

The layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorDivider"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabAddCity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_plus"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:focusable="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently i faced may problem using
28.0.0-** library's

So i suggest u

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

And Change

```
 compileSdkVersion 27
 targetSdkVersion 27
```

Floating Button Example

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

add Dimesn

```
dimens.xml
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and I suggestion once again see the example for more clearance
https://www.androidhive.info/2015/12/android-material-design-floating-action-button/

Comment: Hey ashvin, can you confirm if it was a design library issue
even i am facing similar issue with fab

Comment: @Neji sir i am not sure about that this problem was fix by google or not but we solve this problem by downgrading the library version

Comment: i have done the same thing and it is working fine, were you using svg file for the icon or a png

Comment: i am using png sir

Comment: @Neji this may more help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940219/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-android-studio-3-1-3

Comment: @Neji any time sir

Comment: @Neji can i know you full name i want to save your number

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

`app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"`

It makes the transparent part to have a background color of your choice.

So you can replace it with

`android:tint="@android:color/colorPrimaryDark"`

or

`android:tint="@android:color/background_light"` (if you want white color)

or you can just replace your code with this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fabAddCity"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:tint="@android:color/background_light"
app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
app:borderWidth="0dp"
android:focusable="true"/>
```

I realised you are using colorPrimaryDark for your tint, if you insisted to use, change it to

`android:tint="@android:color/colorPrimaryDark"`

Answer (score 0):

First drawables should be in the proper drawable folder not the `mipmap` folder.  Second it looks like the image you are using is being displayed but may not be the color you want.  If that is the case you can tint it in xml with `android:tint="@color/section_arrowup_color"` but that may not work depending on how your image is formatted.  You can also tint programmatically but that may have the same effect.  Finally you can create a new image asset that is the color you want.  Since it is a plus sign you could easily create a vector drawable and set the colors in xml