# Why floating action button is not displaying any src image and backgroud?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am trying to add image and background to a floating action button in the coordinator layout but I am not getting any image preview and background-color

fragment_task.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_tasks"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:tint="@color/teal_200"

        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my build.gradle maybe this can help identify the problem

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codinginflow.mvvmtodo"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Default dependencies
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$ktxVersion"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appCompatVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$materialVersion"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintLayoutVersion"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$testExtJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion"

    // Fragment
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragmentVersion"

    // Lifecycle + ViewModel & LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:$lifecycleVersion"

    // Navigation Component
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion"

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"

    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutinesVersion"

    // Dagger Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hiltVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hiltVersion"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:$hiltAndroidXVersion"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$hiltAndroidXVersion"

    // DataStore
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:$dataStoreVersion"

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

[image: XML preview]

Floating button is at the bottom end

Tell me which other files do you need and I will edit the question.

Comment: Could you tell the materialVersion ?

Comment: @Manu ```materialVersion = "1.3.0-alpha03"```

Comment: Could you please try with 1.3.0 and try implementing @Muhammad Ahmed's answer and do let me know if that's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was occurred because of a bug and the error was `Path.op` is not supported

So the solution is to just update the Gradle file with

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'`

Comment: `alpha` versions are most unstable and then comes `beta` which is more stable than `alpha` still a lot of potential bug and issues are there then finally comes the `stable` version. always try to use a stable version till the time you really want to use some feature that is yet in either the `alpha` or `beta` stage only.

Did you tried `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right but it worked for me .

Comment: and this `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'` ?

Comment: but apart from the material design version, my answer did helped you right to choose the correct parameters like `tint` `srcCompat`  and `backgroundTint` right ?

Answer (score 2):

try `app:srcCompat` for image and `app:backgroundTint` for background colour

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `app:icon`, at least it works with ExtendedFloatingActionButton

Comment: Maybe this can help you <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069190/how-do-i-display-icon-on-floatingactionbutton>

Answer (score 1):

```
    android:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_error"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
    app:tint="@color/teal_200"
```

You need to add this namespace in your parent layout.

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

[image]

**Note:** if you choose a black background and don't change the colour of the icon using `tint` it will be black by default and you will not able to see the icon

Comment: It didn't work, I uploaded an image preview take a look, please.

Comment: can you also please provide the xml which rendered your new image

Comment: you uploded the image where your floating icon is showing white squared view , so you must have changed something in XML, so can you share the updated XML as well

Comment: I think it's a bug bcoz when I tried to add a hint in editText it didn't show anything but running fine in the emulator.

Comment: the solution I provided is working fine when you run on the device? it's only failing in android studio preview?

Comment: Yup the solution even I made is running fine in the emulator I found the solution I will update it it's a bug in the material library.

Comment: are your Android studio and all the dependencies are up to date, because if that is an bug in material design it should have happened to me as well, my Android studio and all the libraries were to the latest version and those are working fine to me as per the solution I shared

Comment: Do you have this version of the material library - ```implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'```  ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232511/discussion-between-batman-x-and-dinkar-kumar).

Comment: yes , implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'

Comment: `alpha` versions are most unstable and then comes `beta` which is more stable than `alpha` still a lot of potential bug and issues are there then finally comes the `stable` version. always try to use a stable version till the time you really want to use some feature that is yet in either the `alpha` or `beta` stage only.